# Choice Exception Strategy and Preserving Payload

Tags: mule, mule-component

I want to be able to use a choice-exception-strategy with Mule. However, I want to be able to preserve the original payload in the flow. So that I can pass the payload and some properties to another flow, Below is my attempt at doing that. Is that a legal way of doing it? Will the property be preserved so I can retrieve from the vm dlq at the other end?

```
      <flow name="myFlow"> 
      <vm:inbound-endpoint path="requests"/>
      <set-variable variableName="originalPayload" value="#[payload]"/>
     <catch-exception-strategy when="#
       [exception.causedBy(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)]">
              <set-payload value="#[flowVars['originalPayload']"/>
              <set-property propertyName="props" value="">
              <vm:outbound-endpoint path="dlq"/>
       </catch-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy when="#
             [exception.causedBy(java.lang.IllegalStateException)]">
              <set-payload value="#[flowVars['originalPayload']"/>
              <set-property propertyName="props" value="....">
              <vm:outbound-endpoint path="dlq"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
```

Comment: `<set-payload value="#[flowVars['originalPayload']]"/>` is redundant, because the payload is the same as inside of `myFlow`. your are probably looking for outbound properties, just like Alex Fernandez said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case seems valid, but if you want the property/field to be accessible in a transport endpoint it should be an outbound property.